# What should be added to useEffect dependencies in this code?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Here is my code. I'm just displaying offsetX and offsetY in React component. Also dispatching it to Redux store by using `addToStore()`. I'm not sure what values should I add to `deps` array. I added dispatch, but there are offsetX and offsetY states there.

```
function PageMouseMove () {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const [offsetX, setOffsetX] = useState(0)
  const [offsetY, setOffsetY] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    const mouseMove = ({ offsetX, offsetY }) => {
      addToStore({ offsetX, offsetY })(dispatch)
      setOffsetX(offsetX)
      setOffsetY(offsetY)
    }
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove)
    }
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
    <div>
      X - {offsetX}, Y - {offsetY}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your dependencies are the list of variables that will trigger the useEffect. If you want to trigger the useEffect when offsetX or offsetY changes, you should add them to the array

Answer (score 2):

As [@Nicolai Mons Mogensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2953107/nicolai-mons-mogensen) mentions in the comments, the dependencies that you add to the `useEffect(fn,[deps])` method are the variables that will trigger the function.

I would add that the `useEffect` function will get triggered *when the variables change*.

Your function looks correct, but is missing a closing curly, which I assume is a copy-paste error.

Personally, I would change the variable names in the hook to avoid confusion. Like so:

```js
function PageMouseMove() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [offsetX, setOffsetX] = useState(0);
  const [offsetY, setOffsetY] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const mouseMove = ({ offX, offY }) => {
      addToStore({ offsetX: offX, offsetY: offY })(dispatch);
      setOffsetX(offX);
      setOffsetY(offY);
    };
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
    };
  }, [dispatch]);
}
```

Comment: Ok great, it works. I edited the code so full component can be seen now. Thanks!